# How to create a FloatingActionButton menu

Tags: android, button

I want to create a floating button in Android that when it is clicked or selected it will show a menu or choices in floating button form. Can you show me the simplest way to do this?

The link below is the sample that I want to create.

This is the floating button I want to create in my Android application:
[image: This is the floating button I want to create in my Android application]

Also this is the error I'm getting when it renders it happens when I include FloatingActionsMenu on my activity_main.xml

The error Im getting when it is rendering:
[image: The error Im getting when it is rendering]

My activity_mail.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".com.helen.app.helen.MainActivity">

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/mainFloatButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
        >
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/noteFloatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_planner"
            />
 </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```